# Run a python script independently when a method is called

Tags: python, django

I am writing a django application where I need to call a python script, say `foo.py` when a method `bar` is called. The script `foo.py` can take a lot of time to execute as it iterates over millions of rows in database. That is why I don't want to wait for its output, I want the file to be executed purely by the OS. I have tried:

```
execfile
os.system
subprocess.Popen
subprocess.call
```

But they all wait for the file to produce an output. How can I achieve this? Is there a module that I am missing or can I write an "observer script" that observes if the `bar` method is called, it will run the `foo.py` file independently without and let the method finish execution instead of waiting.

Comment: Take a look at celery. Allows you to run tasks asynchronously  http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you did something incorrect, because pure subprocess.Popen doesn't wait for end of child process...

Just tried with following example:

bar.py:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['python', 'foo.py'])
print '123'
```

foo.py:

```
import time

time.sleep(50)
```

Run bar.py:

And I immediately see the "123" output and also I see "python" in processes list

Comment: I am running the file like this: `subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', 'foo.py'])` Is there a flag that must be set so that the first script didn't wait for output?

Comment: see edited answer, just tried and it worked as expected, w\o waiting

Comment: Does the script bar.py finish execution or is that script in the processes list as well?

Comment: bar.py finishes execution and leaves foo.py execution.

Comment: Yes, the function returns before the execution of second script. Thanks!